# How to throw an exception if a method is executed from main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have a class with severeal methods which extract data from a sqlite database. I would like to "force" the users of this class to call these methods in a thread or an asynctask.

**How can i prevent a method to run on the main thread ?**

I would like to achieve something similar to the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException thrown when you try to do some networking on the ui thread.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do something like:

```
if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
   throw new DontDoThisOnUiThreadPleaseException();
}
```

Source: [Looper.getMainLooper()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#getMainLooper()) and [Looper.myLooper()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#myLooper()).

Answer (score 4):

From Google Volley library :

```
 private void throwIfOnMainThread() {
        if (Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Must not be invoked from the main thread.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (Looper.getMainLooper().equals(Looper.myLooper())) {
     throw new MyException("Don't do it on the UI thread");
 }
```

Try this it should work. Of course create your own exception or use existing one.

Answer (score 0):

see Looper documentation to check if you are running in the ui thread or not